# Использование оператора расширения на практике

Tags: javascript

В каких задачах веб-программирования может использоваться оператор `...` из [Остаточные параметры и оператор расширения](https://learn.javascript.ru/rest-parameters-spread-operator) (в каких функциях по семантике применения, возможно в каких-то известных сайтах, возможно при создании некоторых объектов и работе с ними - приведите конкретные примеры)?

Comment: в массив затолкать массив, но чтобы все было на 1м уровне

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=spread+%5Bjavascript%5D

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4+%5Bjavascript%5D

Answer (score 0):

Для веба, одно из распространённых применений — превращение Iterable в массив, если нужны методы массива:

```js
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')].map(a => a.href)
);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/">
<a href="https://example.com/">
```